# Rails validating that password_confirmation is present when password is also present or has been changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I've got the following User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Users table has the necessary password_digest field
  has_secure_password
  attr_accessible :login_name, :password, :password_confirmation

  validates :login_name, :presence=>true, :uniqueness=>true

  # I run this validation on :create so that user 
  # can edit login_name without having to enter password      
  validates :password,:presence=>true,:length=>{:minimum=>6},:on=>:create

  # this should only run if the password has changed
  validates :password_confirmation, 
            :presence=>true, :if => :password_digest_changed?
end
```

These validations don't quite do what I was hoping they would. It's possible to do the following:

```
# rails console
u = User.new :login_name=>"stephen"
u.valid? 
# => false
u.errors 
# => :password_digest=>["can't be blank"], 
# => :password=>["can't be blank", "please enter at least 6 characters"]}

# so far so good, let's give it a password and a valid confirmation
u.password="password"
u.password_confirmation="password"

# at this point the record is valid and does save
u.save
# => true

# but we can now submit a blank password from console
u.password=""
# => true
u.password_confirmation=""
# => true

u.save
# => true
# oh noes
```

So what I want is the following:

- password required on create, must be  6 chars in long
- password_confirmation required on create, must match password
- user should not have to submit password when updating login_name
- password can not be deleted on update

Something which is confusing me is that rails throws a **no method** error if I use `password_changed?` as opposed to `:password_digest_changed?` in my password_confirmation validation. I don't understand why.

So does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`password` isn't a column in the database, right?  Just an attribute?

So there is no `password_changed?` method, which would be available if `password` were a column.  Rather you should just check to see if `password` is set at all.

Something like:

```
validates :password_confirmation, :presence => true, :if => '!password.nil?'
```

Although that solves the initial problem you were having, it still won't quite do what you want, as it's only checking presence, and you need it to be present *and* match password.  Something like the following should work (in combination with the above validation).

```
validates :password, 
          # you only need presence on create
          :presence => { :on => :create },
          # allow_nil for length (presence will handle it on create)
          :length   => { :minimum => 6, :allow_nil => true },
          # and use confirmation to ensure they always match
          :confirmation => true
```

If you've never seen `:confirmation` before, it's a standard validation that looks for `foo` and `foo_confirmation` and makes sure they're the same.

Note that you still need to check for the presence of `password_confirmation`

Comment: Ahh, you're right, password and password_confirmation are not db fields so that explains why I don't have access to dirty methods for them. The user is still able to delete their password on update, and can shorten it to less than 6 chars too. Which is my main problem here

Comment: I edited it to address your other concerns.  Looks like it should work.

Comment: Thanks your code was very close to what I ended up using. In the end I was able to remove the `:presence` validation because `secure_password` already checks for presence of `:password_digest`. I made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/1308130) to remind myself in future